# VPC access policy for S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a VPC, with a VPC endpoint that is associated with a particular route table, say RTB1. Subnet1 uses RTB1 while Subnet2 doesn't.

If I attach a policy to the S3 bucket, specifying the vpc-ID as in the policy below:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "Policy1415115909152",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPC-only",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my_secure_bucket",
                   "arn:aws:s3:::my_secure_bucket/*"],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-111bbb22"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Will this allow instances in Subnet2 to access the S3 bucket? Even though those instances are not routed through RBT1, which has the vpc-endpoint entry?

Comment: Theoretically, Subnet2 (going straight to S3 via the Internet) will not be allowed to access the bucket. Give it a try and let us know what you found!

Comment: Hi John, You are right. Subnet2 traffic is not able to access the bucket. When specifying the vpc-id, only subnets behind vpc endpoints are able to access the bucket. Thanks.

Comment: @NarayananM If you could, it would be handy if you could write up what you found as an answer to your question. That way the next person through here will know all the details.

Comment: Hi @nelsonda,

couldn't figure out how to format text for a comment. So i've posted the summary as an answer...

Comment: @NarayananM You did the right thing! Just because you figured out the answer to your own question does not make it any less an answer. One of the core ideas behind StackOverflow is that formulating good questions helps to answer them!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a summary of the behavior:

```
Scenario: Assume there is 
- 1 VPC, vpc-111bbb22 
- 3 subnets 
    *subnet-1111 behind s3 vpc endpoint vpce-1111, 
    *subnet-2222 behind s3 vpce-2222 and 
    *subnet-3333 which is not associated with any vpc endpoint. 
- 1 S3 bucket named my_secure_bucket (NOTE: this bucket has to be in the same region as the VPC/VPC endpoints)

Using the above bucket policy, the accessibility is as follows:
subnet-1111 - can access
subnet-2222 - can access
subnet-3333 - cannot access
```