# What is the difference between S3 bucket policies and S3 VPC endpoints?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I was curious to know what the functional difference is for creating an S3 bucket with a bucket policy like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPC-only",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket",
                   "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-111bbb22"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

versus creating a VPC endpoint like:

```
{
    "Name": "example-vpc-ap",
    "Bucket": "example-bucket",
    "NetworkOrigin": "VPC",
    "VpcConfiguration": {
        "VpcId": "vpc-111bbb22"
    },
    "CreationDate": "2019-11-27T00:00:00Z"
}
```

Are they functionally equivalent? Is one being depricated or a best practice? It is not clear what the answer is after referencing:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/creating-access-points.html#access-points-vpc
- [VPC access policy for S3 buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56382956/vpc-access-policy-for-s3-buckets)
- [S3 VPC end point Bucket policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451435/s3-vpc-end-point-bucket-policy)

Thanks

Comment: They are not in any way related. The VPC endpoint just reduces bandwidth costs when private instances interact with S3 (via bypassing the NAT gateway). It has not effect on authentication or authorization.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `aws:sourceVpc` can only be used in conjunction with a VPC Endpoint.

From [Example Bucket Policies for VPC Endpoints for Amazon S3 - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies-vpc-endpoint.html#example-bucket-policies-restrict-access-vpc):

> You can create a bucket policy that restricts access to a specific VPC by using the `aws:SourceVpc` condition. This is useful if you have multiple VPC endpoints configured in the same VPC, and you want to manage access to your Amazon S3 buckets for all of your endpoints.

The VPC Endpoint definition shown in your Question is simply saying that the Endpoint is connected to a specific VPC. It does *not* restrict bucket access to only that Endpoint. Users could still access the bucket via the Internet or another endpoint.

I will, however, admit that all these endpoints and configurations are quite confusing!

Comment: From what you and @jordanm are saying... the second example would not restrict access in any way, but instead would create an additional way to access the bucket? only the first snippet would actually restrict access.